# How to do telnet to a host name and port and execute cp(copy) command to copy a file to the present working directory using a bash script

Tags: bash, telnet

I have a bash script called copy_telnet.sh and i want to copy some file from the telnet to the present working directory from where i am running the copy_telnet.sh file. Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
{ sleep 5; echo "ls -lrt /var/log"; sleep 5; echo "cp /var/log/tmp.log ."; sleep 5; } | telnet abc01 2020
```

When i try executing above i am getting below error.

```
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to abc01.
Escape character is '^]'.
ls -lrt /var/log
Password:

Login incorrect
login: Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I don't know the way to inject/give the username and password in my command and not sure about the sleep timer to make my command work. If anyone helps to achieve my requirement which world be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want `scp` or the like, not `telnet`.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Thanks for your idea. Yes i need to scp the file, but for that i need to telnet to the system right?. Is it possible to scp the file from a telnet session secured with username and password, without doing telnet to the system?